# NuGet Package Manager in VS2019 not restoring interop dll for System.Data.SQLite.Core

Tags: git, sqlite, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have a simple .NET Framework console app that uses SQLite. I have installed the System.Data.SQLite.Core NuGet package. When I first build and run the program, everything works fine. Then I clean up my project (Build - Clean Solution), and commit the project to a Git repository. If I clone the repo, and build and run the app, it fails and I get:

> System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll':
> The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x8007007E)'

If I right-click my solution in Solution Explorer and select Restore NuGet Packages, it tells me "All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore." Rebuilding and running the app still gives me the System.DllNotFoundException. But if I use the package manager console (Tools - NuGet Package Manager - Package Manager Console) and run "Update-Package –reinstall", then the app works again.

It appears that the Package Manager is not normally restoring "C:...\SQLite2\SQLite2\bin\Debug\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll".

Am I missing something? Shouldn't this be automatic? What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: What is your `Default package management format` in Tools/Options/Nuget Package Manager/General?

Comment: @DylanZhu-MSFT I have no idea what this means, but apparently it is "Packages.config".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and all the answers here on SO or somewhere else where quite old and didn't apply. It seems that recently MSBuild caught a bug that shows up with the SQLite Nuget package deployment, see more details at https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/50a6f798876b5a18?t=h

The solution was to update my Visual Studio 2019. Running 16.11.1 the build process will put the x86 and x64 interop dlls into the appropriage folders again.

Comment: Creating a a fresh project, I ran into the same problem again. It turned out that the solution also requires the references to be using the PackageReference format.

Answer (score 0):

The `Packages.config` format will download the package in your solution path and add a dll into your project. If there is something wrong about the dll reference the in project, the `package.config` cannot detect and restore it.

You can try to update the format to `PackageReference`, the cache package will be automatically downloaded in `%UserProfile%/.nuget` folder and directly make the package be a reference.